# com.android.internal.R.id.content cannot be resolved to a variable in alarm clock code

Tags: android-layout

I am using the alarm clock code that I found and trying to customize it.

But I get this error : "com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable "
for code:

```
    getListView().setItemsCanFocus(true);

    // Grab the content view so we can modify it.
    FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView()
            .findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.content);
```

I am not sure what this piece of code is doing ( so that I could change it)
Can you please help me resolve this by some alternative piece of code?

Answer (score 14):

The solution is simple.

---

Just replace: `com.android.internal.R.id.content` with `android.R.id.content`

Comment: Worked for me without any problems!

Comment: there is no representation of com.android.internal.R.id.minute in android.R.id :(

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use R.id.content, you need to have a view by that name in layout.

In your gen->R.java file there should be an int named content which corresponds to a view which should be declared in your res->layout folder. This int would be created automatically by Android.

Comment: What type of view should i declare in the layout foldeR? framelayout view?